# spring mvc file upload - file name to support International language

Tags: java, spring-mvc, file-upload, encoding, utf-8

In my spring mvc application.On file upload want to support International language for file name.
Ex: I the file name in Chinese language, it should not changed to  ?????.
I am trying to use this

```
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

But it is not working.Please help on this.

Comment: Do you have any filter for the web project ?

Comment: yes, also it is working fine with filter CharacterEncodingFilter. but don't want to use any filter.it will good if it can resolve by any Resolver

Comment: I don't sure that spring has encoder resolver. But if you want to do with `CommonsMultipartResolver` then `<beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>` seems ok.

Comment: Same I tried, it is not working